# Laravel mix says build successfully but changes won't take effect

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

Every time I run either `npm run` `dev`, `prod`, `hot` or `watch` the build is successful, well at least that's what laravel-mix tells

But when I try to test the changes on the web app there isn't any effect on play, although the build was finished

Comment: After Laravel mix successfully builds, the changes on the web app won't be displayed in the web browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to refresh (Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R) my browser after the build is complete, or open a new tab or other browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `npm run watch-poll` in a new web browser.

Comment: that helped a little, but in the end `Ctrl+F5`, opening on other browser or opening in new private tabs solve it. It was a cache problem